# Is there a way to obtain the path to ProgramData in Windows using javascript?

Tags: javascript

I need to obtain the path to the APPDATA for the current user in Windows(XP, Vista, 7, 8), using javascript.
Is there a way to do this?

Comment: Javascript in what environment?

Comment: I meant in a browser, but I'd got my answer by Aldo

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Short answer is no. However you can use activex to obtain it. But that works only in IE